# How to set very low height of snackbar in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

**How to set a height on SnackBar and How Center on Text on SnackBar? I used Positioned and SozedBox also.**
[image]

```
  _showSnackBar(GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content:SizedBox(child:Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Connection dropped.", style:
      TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.center,)),height: 1.0),),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

just do the following:

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
  content: Container(
    height: 50.0,
      child: Center(
          child: Text(
        "Connection dropped.",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      )),
      ),
  duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
);
_scaffoldKey.currentState
    .showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Comment: same issue bro.. I used height: 1.0. same result

Comment: i tested the code it is working, what is the issue that is happening with you?

Comment: any solution bro

Comment: check the source code of the snackbar, i think there is a constant vertical padding, so when you want to add a fixed height of 1.0, it will not be possible for you to center the content

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since the question has been asked but It might help someone with the same problem. I had the same problem no matter how small Content I used, my SnackBar was big. So, I explicitly set the padding and it `SOLVED` my problem.

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Center(
        child: Text(
          "Connection dropped.",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      //behavior: SnackBarBehavior.fixed,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
      //margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal:5),
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this, it works.

```
void _showSnackBar(String txt) {         
  _scaffoldstate.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Container(
      height: 1.0,
      child: Text(txt, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: you need to use less fontSize!

Comment: same result when use height: 0.1

Comment: But, using 0.1 height. Its not reduce size